# BibTeX Changes "U.S" to "U.C.", How to Correct?

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

I have noticed that BibTeX will change the initials "U.S." (as in "United States") to "U.C."  This has happened using both IEEE and Elsevier document classes, and it works the same with and without punctuation.  This happens formatting the citation as either `@misc` and `@techreport` (it may also happen with additional formats, but I have not tried).

For example, when attempting to cite

> "U.S. Census Bureau"

the output becomes

> "U.C. Bureau"

Here's a code sample.

```
\documentclass[5p]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}

Citation \cite{census:2011}.

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

with BibTex entry:

```
@misc{census:2011,
  author        = "U.S. Census Bureau",
  title         = "2010 Census",
  howpublished  = "U.S. Department of Commerce",
  month         = feb,
  year          = "2011",
}
```

produces:

> [1] U. C. Bureau, 2010 census, U.S. Department of Commerce (Feb.
>   2011).

I can use `\verb` to force the correct lettering, but the resulting font and font size is different than the surrounding text.  How can I correct this in a citation?

Is this some well known inside joke I'm not in on?

Comment: Can you post a minimal working document that shows the issue?

Comment: I wrote the same thing as the accepted answer as a comment but then deleted it as that would explain `U C Bureau` But you claim to have got `U C Census Bureau` with both `C` and `Census` assuming that is a typo in your question could you edit it for future reference.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Fixed.

Comment: In addition to Tyler's answer below, you should write `U.S.~Census Bureau` (and `U.S.~Department of Commerce`) in order to prevent the space after the second full stop from being enlarged.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

BibTeX is likely interpreting U.S. Census Bureau as a personal name, and abbreviating U.S. to U. and Census to C. You need to wrap the whole name in {}:

```
author = {{U.S. Census Bureau}},
```